# Returning value of variable inside a struct when the struct is rvalue of an assignment

Tags: c++, struct, operator-overloading, assignment-operator

I have the following code:

```
class example {
   int x;
   inline void operator=(int value) { x = value; }
};

int main() {
   example foo { 100 };
   int bar = foo;
}
```

The `int bar = foo;` obviously doesn't work, because I'm trying to assign a variable of type `example` to a variable of type `int`.

Is it possible to retrieve the `x` variable **without using a getter function and without using** `operator.`? If so, is it still possible to do purely by code inside the struct, and keeping the `int bar = foo;` as is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a [conversion function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator) to allow [implicit conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion)

```cpp
struct example {
   int x;
   inline void operator=(int value) { x = value; }

   operator int() const
   {
       return x;
   }
};

int main() {
   example foo { 100 };
   int bar = foo;
}
```